# Filtar productos tipo reserva por rango de fecha con WC_Product_Query

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

estoy trabajando en un plugin para obtener todos los productos (simples o reservas) y actualmente estoy agregando opciones de filtro. Logré agregar un filtro de categorías múltiples, pero ahora quiero agregar también un filtro de rango de fechas para mostrar solo las reservas con existencias en esos días, aquí está el código que tengo:

```
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                $tax_query[] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $value,
                );
            }
        }else{
            $tax_query = array();
        }

        $types = ['simple','booking'];
        $visibility = ['catalog','search'];
        $args = array(
            'type'      => $types,
            'status'    => 'publish',
            'orderby'   => 'ID',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'limit'     => -1,
            'tax_query' => $tax_query
        );

        $query = new WC_Product_Query($args);
        $products = $query->get_products();
```

Al estar enviando variables distintas a las categorías tendría que filtrar lo que recibo via $_POST, esto no es problema pero no encuentro los campos fecha de inicio y la fecha de finalización y no he encontrado ningún ejemplo de como unir esto con mi tax_query actual. Cualquier ayuda será apreciada
Gracias